# Is XP from challenges/commendations/double XP affected by the daily XP cap?

Tags: halo-4

I have heard [varying reports](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632877-halo-4/64567928) about the exact amount of the online XP limit.  However, given that some of the challenges and commendations have fairly big payouts, and since Mountain Dew is running another one of their beloved [double XP](http://www.dewxp.com/#/Main/Redeem) promotions, I'm curious if the cap applies to these XP "bonuses".  It would be kind of crappy to hit a big payout, and then saturate at the cap and get no credit for it, so if that is the case I'd like to know about it and maybe avoid hitting the big challenges/commendations, and avoid using double XP, when I know I'm at the cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Daily Experience Cap applies to all of the above. When it it hit you will get no more experience until the next day. Any commendations or challenges you complete while capped will be forever lost. Double XP is not consumed after hitting the cap though. I'm Currently stuck at 59 and have been hitting the cap every day for the past week. If you get a big payout on experience doing something like spartan ops or just by getting a lot of commendations that match, and you're close to the xp cap, you will only be allowed to gain enough experience to hit the cap and then the leftover is also lost forever. I personally think that commendations and challenges should be exempt from this cap considering you can only accomplish them once, but for now there are no exceptions. once you hit the cap, you're done gaining experience for the day.

Comment: Moved check, for more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it applies to all of the above.

Comment: Hi @Ray and welcome to Arqade!  I appreciate the answer, but could you explain your source and possibly give a bit more detail (if applicable)?

Answer (score 1):

I can give a source, since I'm rank 56 and have been hitting the cap for the past week now. They fixed it so it doesn't waste your double XP when you are capped. The challenges and commendations though are wasted.